# USB COMMAND INTERRUPT, DMA, I/O PORTS IN WINDOWS 7-EXAMPLES

Tags: usb, interface

In the present, there is virtually no other interfaces between external electrical circuits and the internal resources of computers, than USB (excluding PCI, PCIE...cards, useless in the case of laptops). Despite this reality, complete examples from project to schematics on accessing internal resources of the computer (IRQ, DMA, I / O ports) are not available in the case of USB bus. 
What are the SIMPLEST and COMPLETE examples, from project to schematics, (by using the USB bus) concerning:

1) DETECTION AND HANDLING OF FREE HARDWARE INTERRUPTS RESOURCES IN WINDOWS 7-10

2) DETECTION AND HANDLING OF FREE DMA RESOURCES IN WINDOWS 7-10

3) DETECTION AND HANDLING OF FREE I/O PORTS IN WINDOWS 7-10.

4) CREATION OF NEW (USB ACCESSIBLE) EXTERNAL I/O PORTS, DMA CHANNEL, HARDWARE INTERRUPTS.

A GOOD EXAMPLE WOULD BE THE COMPLETE ANALYSIS OF INTERFACING THE  IRQ CONTROLLER 8259, DMA CONTROLLER 8237,  PIO 8255 (OR SOME EQUIVALENT), VIA THE USB BUS.

THE CURRENT STATE OF EXISTING INFORMATION ON THE NET ABOUT THIS TOPIC, MAKES ME UNDERSTAND THE DEPTH OF HEISENBERG'S APHORISM: 
„ Even for the physicist the description in plain language will be the criterion of the degree of understanding that has been reached”. IN THIS CASE, THE PLAIN LANGUAGE IS MISSING...

Comment: There's no 8259 in a modern PC? What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This isn't a design or research service. If you were even half way serious you would have found plenty of resources to start developing and researching. But hey, you can always budget $125 per hour for a professional to do it all for you. Or $150 if you're going to be shouting and demanding like above.

Answer (score 2):

> INTERFACING THE IRQ CONTROLLER 8259, DMA CONTROLLER 8237, PIO 8255 (OR SOME EQUIVALENT), VIA THE USB BUS.

You won't be able to interface these ueber-old chips via USB. Note that these are no longer phyiscally present in a PC (but might be emulated somehow). USB requires more complex logic to be implemented in any device on the bus.

Almost all the magic of USB is in the host controller. That means the driver developer of a USB device has *never* to worry about DMA, ports and interrupts, as these are always handled by the host controller driver supplied with the OS.

Comment: I understand your comments. But, as you say, "USB requires more complex logic to be implemented in any device on the bus." What I don't find, is A SIMPLE AND COMPLETE EXAMPLE concerning this logic. How short can be this example? Was there some COMPLETE EXAMPLE?

Comment: A complete example would be about as big as a book. See for example the [No USB? No Problem. CCC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFY_A3jcI28)

Comment: Thank you for your advice; the conference was useful, and I will  reflect on everything I've said. Regarding my requests, I think that are not unreasonable. I am expert (software and hardware) in the old ISA bus. Arstech.com company's achievements (see [link](http://www.arstech.com/install/cms-display/ste_usl.html))  allowed me to hope. It seems that my problems are too small for the present.

Answer (score 0):

when you are talking about operating system, the OS has drivers for the underlying standard hardwares, if you wand to use the hardware from the OS level you have standard libraries to get the in and out of it, so you need to only know what library to use and access that hardware, like USB, Serial port (com-1, com-2, etc)

If you have custom hardware and need have access to the hardware, then you need to know how write device drivers for the respective OS